# How to make my datepicker show up in modal

Tags: angular, datepicker, modal-dialog, frontend

I'm using angular for a frontend. It's a very simple app, and it's working perfectly except for BsDatePicker. When I open my modal from the form, and click on datepicker, it closes the modal and shows the datepicker without css loaded. It should just load the datepicker and let me choose the date.

However, when it opens the datepicker, upon closing the modal, when I choose the date, and reopen modal, it registers it and does the rest fine.

show-modal.component.html

```
<div id="date">Date:</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="showDialog()">Open</button>

<modal id="modal_1" class="hhidden">
    <form name="datePickerForm" (submit)="closeDialog()">  
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-12 col-md-4 form-group">

        <input type="text"
           placeholder="Datepicker"
           class="form-control"
           bsDatepicker
           [bsConfig]="{ isAnimated: true }" name="date"
           [(ngModel)]="date">
      </div>    
      
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Close Dialog</button>
    </form>
</modal>
```

show-modal.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
import { DatePickerComponent } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-showmodal',
  templateUrl: './show-modal.component.html',
    styles: []
})
export class ShowModalComponent {
    date: Date;
    @Output() event= new EventEmitter();
    showDialog(){
        let modal_t  = document.getElementById('modal_1');
        modal_t.classList.remove('hhidden');
        modal_t.classList.add('sshow');
        backdrop  : 'static';
        keyboard  : false;
    }
    closeDialog() {
        let modal_t  = document.getElementById('modal_1');
        modal_t.classList.remove('sshow');
        modal_t.classList.add('hhidden');
        this.event.emit(formatDate(this.date, 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'en'));
    }
}
```

modal.component.html

```
<div class="mmodal"> 
    <div class="mmodal-body">
        <ng-content >
        </ng-content>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="mmodal-background"></div>
```

modal.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'modal',
  templateUrl: `./modal.component.html`,
styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css']
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }
  ngOnInit() {
      // we added this so that when the backdrop is clicked the modal is closed.
      this.el.nativeElement.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
          this.close()
      })
  }
  close() {
      this.el.nativeElement.classList.remove('sshow');
      this.el.nativeElement.classList.add('hhidden');
  }
  setDate(data) {
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = "Date: " + data;
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'NewOne';
  setDate(data) {
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = "Date: " + data;
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ModalComponent } from './modal/modal.component';
import { ShowModalComponent } from './show-modal/show-modal.component';
import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ModalComponent,
    ShowModalComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { 
}
```

app.component.html

```
<app-showmodal (event)="setDate($event)" ><modal></modal></app-showmodal>
```

I hope someone can help. If I didn't post something you need, feel free to ask.